How to call a global function within a namespace function of the same name in C++?
I have tried creating a namespace function with the same name as a global function in C++ which resulted in recursive calls to the namespace function.
For example, if I create a namespace function called write() intended to be a wrapper around write() provided by the unistd.h, it results in recursive calls to file_utils::write() and the global one is never called.
Here is a more detailed explanation:
namespace file_utils
{
ssize_t write(int fd, const void* buffer, std::size_t size)
{
    ssize_t bytes_written = write(fd, buffer, size);  // a recursive call
    if (bytes_written < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "write failed with errno: " << errno << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    return bytes_written;
}

} // namespace file_utils

I could change the name to something like write_ex but I wanted to know what is the best way to prevent it?
I tried renaming it to write_ex and it worked, but I wanted to know what is the best practice for handling such scenarios.
Link to complete code: https://godbolt.org/z/r1n7E1dYP

::write(fd, buffer, size); will call 'global' write.

Your example could be much simpler. When you're having trouble sorting out how to write some bit of code, eliminate distractions. void f(); namespace x { void f() { ::f(); } }.
